# MS Office Word macro, play sound upon scrolling through certain pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've already got [the useful tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732840/play-any-audio-file-using-vba-excel) of how to play an external audio file. 
And now I'm struggling of how to use it upon reaching a certain page.

I've managed to find that I have to add the stuff below to obtain a list of events I can use:

```
Public WithEvents App As Word.Application
```

And I got a plenty of the events:
[App events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gradt.jpg)
But no one from them seems corresponding to what I need.

1)Find out a certain event I can use, to track any action which might change currently viewed page(mouse scroll, arrows, page up/down, mouse move with selection, or any of others..) and then paste a checking function into.

2)The checking function supposed to obtain number of current page within the document(or it's equivalent) and if we are at a certain page play corresponding sound.

There are 2 main problems I've struggled with, but got no good idea.

I also aware that we can use ActiveX object and insert an audio file into the document, it allows to even not keep the file somewhere, but embeed it into the doc. 
However here I even have no idea of how to trigger playing of the file through VBA. 
But if somebody can advise about it would be perfect because it even more handy, in terms of maintenance(no need to keep external audio files).

Any help is appreciated.
If you know that it's impossible in general, please also let me know, so I can close the topic.

Comment: Word provides no such events as you list. The issue with using an ActiveX object is that it requires the same ActiveX Server (program that executes the sound, in this case) available on every machine where this should work - could be possible, I'm just mentioning the possible limitation. If you can embed the audio as an ActiveX object and execute it as a user then it's possible VBA can "hook into" that programming interface. Press Alt+F9 to see the field code behind the ActiveX control and use the [edit] link to add that to your question.

Comment: @CindyMeister, thanks for your answer and time on it. I struggled with some time but didn't manage to "hook into" unfortunately. So was have to give up with.