# How to play audio in browser control on Excel userform?

Tags: html, excel, vba, audio

I'm trying to show rich text and play audio using a web browser control in userform.

I added "Microsoft Web Browser" control from Tools>Additional Control on the toolbox and added a browser on a userform but I couldn't add audio to the page with the following code.

I switched the offline property to true and changed other properties but nothing changed.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim HTMLcontent As String
  
    HTMLcontent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>"
    HTMLcontent = HTMLcontent & "<a href=""C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Sleep Away.mp3"">/na?/</a>"
    HTMLcontent = HTMLcontent & "<audio src=""C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Sleep Away.mp3"">Doesn't support</audio>"
    HTMLcontent = HTMLcontent & "</body></html>"

    WebBrowser1.navigate "about:blank"
    WebBrowser1.document.Write HTMLcontent

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The web-browser used in the userform is IE11, which doesn't seem to properly support audio.

If you just want to display formatted text in a browser and play a sound to it you can just play the sound via VBA, there are examples on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732840/play-any-audio-file-using-vba-excel) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/can-you-play-sound-via-vba.6747/).