# Excel VBA Get True Folder Path Length (Excluding Tilde)

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that creates a backup file (using .SaveCopyAs) every X times my client saves the file. Recently a client ran into the max folder & file path length which seems to be around 220 characters. I'm trying to catch the long file name but Excel/Windows is replacing the long folder names with ~ (tilde) so I can't get the true path length.

How do I get the actual folder/file path string length and prevent Windows from using the "~"?

```
Sub Backup()
    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook

    BackupFolder = awb.Path & "\Backups"   
    BackupFileName = BackupFolder & "\" & awb.Name
    BackupFileName = BackupFileName & " " & Format(Now(), "mmddhhmm") & ".xlsm"

    'debug.print BackupFileName 
    'Result: D:\MF\DOCUME~1\LATEST~1\MASTER~1\SUPERL~1\SUPERL~1\Backups\TestLength-07021655.xlsm

    'debug.print Len(BackupFileName)
    'Result: 83 but the TRUE length is well over 300 characters

    PathLen = Len(BackupFileName) 'Result: 83
    If PathLen > 215 Then 'This obviously doesn't fire
        BackupFolder = GetDesktop & "BidListBackups"
        BackupFileName = BackupFolder & "\" & awb.Name
        BackupFileName = BackupFileName & " " & sType & Format(Now(), "mmddhhmm") & ".xlsm"
    End If

    With awb
        .SaveCopyAs BackupFileName
    End With

    If PathLen > 215 
        MsgBox "Backup file was saved to your desktop", vbokonly
    End If   
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah this is a tough one i spent a long time trying to get around this but since its roots in the very essence of windows i was never able too :( sry no help

Comment: Have you tried the Win API call `GetLongPathName` ?

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442146/4243498) for code that uses the `GetLongPathName` API. Note that you will need to increase the buffer size from the 165 shown in the code.