# Application.inputbox missing prompt

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've learned that Excel VBA on OSX has been hobbled, but is this a problem in my code or VBA for OSX?   The following  line:

```
FirstYear = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter the first year you wish to import", Type:=1)
```

gives me an inputbox, but no prompt.  Anyone any ideas?  If I use the inputbox function rather than method the prompt works, but then error handling of the cancel button seems to be impossible.

Comment: No clue if it's supported in the OSX version, but [you can test for cancel with `StrPtr`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42015700/4088852).

Comment: Tx - I spotted that one, but as it's unsupported I don't know how well it will survive endless updates in 2016.  I've lost all confidence in Microsoft making anything work reliably in OS X - I've had endless problems with what I suspect is memory leakage or corruption of some sort meaning files give incorrect answers sometimes - but close down, restart, and the right answer comes up!  So heading out into undocumented features leves me trembling :)

Comment: FWIW, I'd be surprised if they yanked `StrPtr` from the OS X version - it's just a very shallow wrapper around whatever VBA is doing internally to manage the string pool.  It's much more likely that MS just drops support OS X entirely.

Comment: Certainly the way they support Excel 2016 on osx at present makes me think they simply want to dump us as users.  I just wish there was an alternative.  Anyone use LibreOffice?  Is the code environment good enough?

Comment: I'm a Linux user, so I'm familiar with LibreOffice.  The coding environment is fine - it's the rest of it that I'm not exactly wild about.  I have a Windows VM specifically for running MS Office applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the `InputBox()` function as follows:

```
Dim FirstYear As Long
On Error Resume Next
Do
    Err.Clear
    FirstYear = InputBox(prompt:="Enter the first year you wish to import")
Loop While Err <> 0 Or Not IsNumeric(FirstYear)
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: @MikeMason, did you get through it?

Comment: Tx - I kludged it and it works - good enough to get the job done rather than to create beautiful code.  I guess what I really need to understand, as a newbie VB programmer (used to do Fortran IV 30 years ago) is WHY it doesn't work - Increasingly believing MSoft simply doesn't care about OSX users.

Comment: You are welcome. And sorry for not providing you _beautiful code_. As for the WHY I believe the same as you, too. But that's my opinion. BTW you may then want to mark this answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you