# VBA returning a dictionary from a function

Tags: excel, vba, function, dictionary, object

Problem: I want to create a function that gets one string and returns a dictionary.
After much reading in SO I reproduced exactly the code given in some questions and I end up with a solution that looks to work. But there are things that I dont understand.

here the code which is a bit long because includes some comments:

```
Private Sub testdictionary()
Dim dict_in_sub As Scripting.Dictionary
    ' Do I really need this??:
    'Set dict_in_sub = New Scripting.Dictionary
    ' or this:
    'Set dict_in_sub =CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Call returning_dict_func("word1.word2")
Set dict_in_sub = returning_dict_func("whatever.second")

MsgBox "in code:" & Chr(10) & dict_in_sub("A") & Chr(10) & dict_in_sub("B")
End Sub
```

This is the function called:

```
Function returning_dict_func(SC As String) As  Scripting.Dictionary
' should this function return a dictionary or an object or a scrippting dictionary??

Dim dictionary_in_function
    Set dictionary_in_function = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

'take the first and second part of the string separated by the period
dictionary_in_function("A") = Mid(SC, 1, InStr(SC, ".") - 1)
dictionary_in_function("B") = Mid(SC, InStr(SC, ".") + 1, Len(SC))

MsgBox dictionary_in_function("A") & Chr(10) & dictionary_in_function("B")
Set returning_dict_func = dictionary_in_function
End Function
```

Even if I got the code running, there are a few things that make returning a dict from a function in VBA strange
Introducing the following changes into the code make it not working:

```
Dim dict_in_sub as Dictionary
' it does not work. What is the difference between dictionary and scrippting.dictionary?

' defining the function as returning a dictionary does not work
Function returning_dict_func(SC As String) As Dictionary

' if both are dictionaries it does not work
 Dim dict_in_sub as Dictionary
 Function returning_dict_func(SC As String) As Dictionary
```

Why is dictionary different than scripting.dictionary?

When should you initialize with

Set dict_modifiers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

thanks

Note:
I had a look to:
a) VBA in Excel 2010: Scripting.Dictionary return value of a function won't pass as parameter to a wrapping function call
b) Returning dictionary from function in vba. Error 450
c) Returning an dictionary object from a function in VBA

Comment: This question is really too broad for this forum.  But two suggestions:  Always use `Option Explicit` at the top of your modules (and, in the VBE, go to Tools/Options and **SET** the option to require variable declaration).  With regard to declaring the dictionary type, search for the differences between late-binding and early-binding.

Comment: I thought so, but just if I get the difference between dictionary and scrippting.dictionary would be enough.

Comment: Either can work.  `Scripting` ensures that the `Dictionary` object is bound to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`.  So if you are using late-binding, it is required when you `CreateObject`.  If you are using early binding, and only one of your references has a `Dictionary` object, then it would be optional.  Others may be able to phrase this better, but that's how I understand it.

Comment: This topic covers about 5 out of 7 of the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429138/are-as-dictionary-and-as-scripting-dictionary-equivalent-for-vba-early-bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `CreateObject` and `New` is briefly you need to reference a library with the object (Microsoft Scripting Runtime) for the latter (`New`), and you don't need to reference anything using `CreateObject`.

You can also have some intellisense hints when you use the latter definition, as the type is declared and known.

You can find more in another answer: [What are the differences between using the New keyword and calling CreateObject in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170070/what-are-the-differences-between-using-the-new-keyword-and-calling-createobject)

As for the Dictionary object, `Scripting.Dictionary` is the right type to use. Read more about it in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object.

And by the way, in VBA you have to assign variables values using `Set` when the value is an object (usually something different than a number or String or Date).

Comment: what is then a simply dictionary. Why does VBA includes the possibility to simply write dim a as dictionary if actually a whole thing of clicking the corresponding library in excel

Comment: Have you referenced the Scripting library?

Comment: referenced is "microsoft scripting runtime" (and some others).

Comment: So maybe one of the others also defined Dictionary ;). If you had only Scripting, both references should work the same I think.

Comment: That is why you should use full reference names `Scripting.Dictionary` to avoid any problems.