# vba inputBox: Alternative Solutions on “cancel” and “OK” with an empty textbox

Tags: vba

For some reason, the solution those two questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181431/vba-inputbox-how-to-tell-difference-between-cancel-and-ok-with-an-empty-tex), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015700/what-are-the-benefits-and-risks-of-using-the-strptr-function-in-vba)) give on how to differentiate between "cancel" and "ok with an empty string" for an inputbox don't always work within a specific code of mine. I wasn't able to reproduce the problem so far so I'm looking for a different solution.

In my scenario, the inputbox pops up with a default value it got from somewhere else. So far I only needed to change this value through the inputbox so the simple check for `if len(inputboxString) = 0 then` to determine if `cancel` was pressed was working well. Now I got the case where I need to "clear" the existing default value. I'm trying to avoid using `StrPtr` for the reason I described above.

Here's the code that worked so far (as long as I don't need to use the inputbox to delete the value, since 'strInputBox = ""' is reserved for the cancel-event and I want to avoid using 'strPtr').

```
Dim strSomeStringFromSomewhere as String
strSomeStringFromSomewhere  = someSubThatGetsTheStringValueFromSomeWhere

Dim strInputBox As String
strInputBox = InputBox(Prompt:="Edit/Delete Value", Title:="Title", Default:=strSomeStringFromSomewhere)

If strInputBox = "" then
    'do nothing cause cancel was pressed
    else
    someSubThatWritesTheChangedStringBackToItsOrigin strInputBox 
    End If
```

The used value is usually some alphanumeric string e.g. `d939d8ej3`.

Any hints/ideas for a different user friendly approach would be welcome. (user meaning the person using the inputbox not the person who implements/maintains the code).

Comment: If you use `Application.Inputbox` you can test `TypeName(returnValue)` - if it's Boolean (False) then the user pressed Cancel.  If you're saying that doesn't always work for you, then a custom UserForm seems like the way to go.

Comment: @TimWilliams Yeah thanks, a custom userform is my plan B...  I thought I ask anyway, maybe s.o. has an idea for a feasible workaround.

Comment: `Application.Inputbox` should work fine - I've never seen that fail...

Comment: @TimWilliams Right, thanks... completely forgot about that one. With `inputBox = Application.InputBox(...)` I catch the cancel through `inputBox = false` and an "empty" input through `inputBox = ""`?!

Comment: Declare the return value as Variant and check `TypeName(theValue)` - if it's "Boolean" (with a value of False) then the user pressed Cancel - otherwise they pressed OK.

Comment: @TimWilliams Why not check if it's false directly?

Comment: You can but I might worry about type coercion (whether or not that's a valid concern is another thing)

Comment: @TimWilliams accouding to [MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.InputBox) it returns false only if the cancel button is pressed or false is entered as a value (`Type = 4`). But you are right, it's always a good idea to check if a return value is within the specified domain. Feel free to post is as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a nice work around, which should work in many other cases as well. In my case a single or multiple spaces are not a valid entries. And since I have to get rid of pre- and succeeding spaces anyway I just use `trim(strInputBox)` which will "clear" my value.

So the user just has to enter a space into the inputbox, which is good enough for prototypes.