# InputBox in Excel difference between ok and cancel

Tags: excel, vba

I want a simple inputbox that doesn't empty the cell if i press cancel,leaving the previous cell contents, but when i press ok it will show in the cell anything that I type in and if i'm not typing in anything it will show an empty cell. (only when ok is pressed).

Comment: See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015700/what-are-the-benefits-and-risks-of-using-the-strptr-function-in-vba. The key is using `StrPtr` on the result, or use `Application.Inputbox` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Application.InputBox Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.InputBox):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AskForInput()
    Dim Response As Variant
    Response = Application.InputBox("type something")

    If Not (VarType(Response) = vbBoolean And Response = False) Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = Response
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that `(VarType(Response) = vbBoolean And Response = False)` checks if cancel was pressed. If the input box is empty and you press OK it will still empty the cell.

Also note that we additionally need to check the `VarType` of the `Response` here otherwise it would consider an input of `0` as `False` and cancel.