# VBA - code taking 5+ mins to search inbox even when match is first email in inbox - how do I speed this up?

Tags: excel, vba

This code currently takes several minutes to run by itself, even when the email is the most recent email in the inbox (i.e., very little to sort through before it hits a match).

```
Sub Info()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim [all sorts of stuff]

Set priorSaveFolder = y.Sheets([SHEET]).Range([LOOKUP])

'Find Mailbox to search for information
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sharedemail = olNS.CreateRecipient("[MAILBOX]")
Set olfldr = olNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(sharedemail, olFolderInbox)
Set folder = olfldr
Set myTasks = folder.Items.Restrict("[Subject]='AP Settlement'")
myTasks.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False

'Search folder, save

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
        For Each objAtt In olMail.Attachments
            If InStr(objAtt.Filename, "MTTAX") Or InStr(objAtt.Filename, "mttax") Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next objAtt
    End If
Next olMail

[MORE CODE BELOW THAT ISN'T TAKING FOREVER]
```

Comment: You exit the inner `for each` that loops over the email's attachments, but not the outer `for each` that loops over the emails. If you need to exit both, [use `goto`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54178768/11683).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search continues as `Exit For` is applied to the inner loop only.

`Exit For` again to exit the outer loop:

```vb
Dim foundFlag As Boolean

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If olMail.Attachments.count > 0 Then
        For Each objAtt In olMail.Attachments
            If InStr(objAtt.FileName, "MTTAX") Or InStr(objAtt.FileName, "mttax") Then
                objAtt.SaveAsFile priorSaveFolder & "MTTAX.html"
                
                foundFlag = True
                
                Exit For
                
            End If
        Next objAtt
    End If
    
    If foundFlag = True Then Exit For
    
Next olMail
```

Comment: thanks! this worked really well, appreciate it! thanks for helping me learn something new! :)

Comment: quick follow-up, if I have multiple of these email searches, can I reuse the same foundFlag, do I need to have multiple foundFlags, or do I reset it in some way?

Comment: If each search is complete before the next starts you can use the same `foundFlag`. Place `foundFlag = False` just before starting a new search. If there is any overlap or for ease of understanding, use as many as you need `foundFlag2`, `foundFlag3` ...

Comment: Thanks again! Really appreciate the help!