# Correction of Case-Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to implement a VBA code with inputbox function. I get the result with IF-Function, but I cannot get the result with CASE-Function.

This is my code with if function where I get the output correctly:

```
Sub test3()
Dim x As String

x = InputBox("What is your age?", "just a moment")

If x = "" Then
MsgBox "You did not answer the question!"
Else
    If IsNumeric(x) Then
        Range("A1").Value = "Your Age:"
        Range("B1").Value = x
    Else
        MsgBox "Please input no text"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I am writing the same code with the same aid with CASE-Function where I get no output:

```
Sub test2()
Dim x As String

x = InputBox("What is your age?", "Just a moment...")

Select Case x

Case Is = ""
   MsgBox "You did not answer the question!"
Case IsNumeric(x)
    Range("A1").Value = "You age:"
    Range("B1").Value = x
Case Else
    MsgBox "Please answer with a numerical value!"
End Select
End Sub
```

I highly appreciate if you can correct my code with CASE-Function!

Comment: `Case Is = ""` doesn't cover the case where the `InputBox` is cancelled.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42015700/4088852).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest the use of the [Application.InputBox method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox) instead of the [InputBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function)

The `InputBox method` has a `data type` parameter used to determine the values that can be accepted by the method.

Try this:

```
Sub Enter_Age()
Dim bAge As Byte, bTry As Byte

Enter_Age:
    bTry = 1 + bTry
    bAge = Application.InputBox("What is your age?", "just a moment", Type:=1)

    Select Case bAge
    Case False
        If bTry = 3 Then
            MsgBox "You did not answer the question!" & vbLf _
                & vbTab & "Process will be cancelled!"
                Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "You did not answer the question!"
            GoTo Enter_Age
        End If

    Case Else
        Range("A1").Value = "Your Age:"
        Range("B1").Value = bAge

    End Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. May I ask you which part of the code refers to the error message "Number is not valid!" regarding inputting the text in the message box?

Comment: That part is not needed because of the data type. Type 1 is used to request a number, if the user enters anything different than a number, the Input Box method shows a message. Suggest reading the pages provided in the links so you can see the advantage of using the method instead of the function.