# How to handle the InputBox cancel button?

Tags: excel, vba

I type in the start date and the end date and execute a code of export from Outlook.

```
Sub ExportFromOutlook()
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date

dteStart = InputBox("What is the start date?", "Export Outlook Calendar")
dteEnd = InputBox("What is the end date?", "Export Outlook Calendar")
Call GetCalData(dteStart, dteEnd)
End Sub
```

I want when I press the **"Cancel button"** on any of the Inputboxes to exit the sub, not to get an error in the VBA code to debug it.

Comment: You will have to trap the error. Each error in VBA will return a specific number. You can handle the error and the, when the user press `Cancel`, then Exit sub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unqualified `InputBox` is [`VBA.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputbox-function). It returns a `String`, not a date, and you [use `StrPtr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20909417/11683) to determine if Cancel was pressed:

```
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim t as string

t = InputBox("What is the start date?", "Export Outlook Calendar")
If StrPtr(t) = 0
  Exit Sub
Else
  dteStart = CDate(t)
End If

t = InputBox("What is the end date?", "Export Outlook Calendar")
If StrPtr(t) = 0
  Exit Sub
Else
  dteEnd = CDate(t)
End If
```

If you switch to Excel's [`Application.InputBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox), which returns Variant, it may become a little bit more straightforward:

```
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date
Dim t as Variant

t = Application.InputBox("What is the start date?", "Export Outlook Calendar", Type:=2)
If t = False
  Exit Sub
Else
  dteStart = CDate(t)
End If

t = Application.InputBox("What is the end date?", "Export Outlook Calendar", Type:=2)
If t = False
  Exit Sub
Else
  dteEnd = CDate(t)
End If
```

Comment: Maybe there should be also an error handler for the case that the user entered something invalid.

Comment: @FunThomas There should be, but there wasn't one originally either.

Comment: Just wanted to prevent the follow up quesion ;-)

Comment: [FYI: `StrPtr` may act slightly decieving and is not always the optimal way of handling `InputBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015700/what-are-the-benefits-and-risks-of-using-the-strptr-function-in-vba)

Comment: Thank you @GSerg, this is working, about the follow up question Thomas said, I would like to approach that too at least a bit, if you are up to it. TIA

Comment: @Flaw98 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1046222/8769365) is a great answer on error handling in VBA.

Comment: @Flaw98 `IsDate` tells you if the string is convertable to date.Use that to direct your logic into asking for a better input.

Comment: As my previous comment suggested, it's better to check for `= vbNullString` or `Len() = 0`. As of now `StrPtr()` only works thanks to the bug in production of `InputBox` by Microsoft

Comment: @Rawrplus I find the answer you've pointed to wrong and misleading. I have [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015700/what-are-the-benefits-and-risks-of-using-the-strptr-function-in-vba#comment99055825_42016288). Checking for `= vbNullString` or `Len() = 0` will give you `True` when the user leaves the input field empty and presses OK. The only correct way to detect a cancel with `VBA.InputBox` (as opposed to `Application.InputBox`) is `StrPtr`.

Comment: So, from what I've read around there are different opinions, in my case I have tested what @Gserg suggested me (the second approach - `Application.InputBox`) and it is working just as perfect. If I were to add the IsDate I should add it to the variable T, am I right?

Comment: `If StrPtr(t) = 0 And (IsDate(t) = False) Then
  Exit Sub`

Comment: @Flaw98 `IsDate` will always be false when `StrPtr` is zero.